# Best pattern for creating closures that are unit testable?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, closures

Given this:

```
var closure = (function() {
    var some_variable;
    var ret = {};

    function some_internal_function() {
        return some_variable;
    };

    function init() {
        some_variable = document.getElementById("canvas");
    }

    ret.some_internal_function = some_internal_function;

    return ret;
}());
```

I'd like to be able to `some_variable` to a mock object during unit testing. But this seems to be impossible. [There used to be a work around with eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255088/best-way-to-test-javascript-functions-that-use-variables-from-a-closure), but that doesn't seem possible anymore.

I'm assuming I'll have to hijack my `init()` function to make the mock I want, but that seems counter to the unit testing philosophy, since I'm essentially depending on the execution of another function to dictate the behavior of the one I want to test!

I've seen some code that passes in an optional context to use during function execution and I assume that's related to testing / getting at internal variables.

I suppose I could fork a new node process, `node -e closure.toString()`, modify the string to `var some_variable = {}; //the mock object`, append a method to return the value (`console.log(closure.some_internal_function())`), pipe back the result to my main process and do `assert()`s with qunit. But that seems like trying to be a hero, when there should be a better way (if anything that seems easier than [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31186948/5343977) ><).

Is there a better way? What's the best pattern for testing this sort of thing?

Comment: What you assign to the `closure` variable above isn't a closure, it's an object. One of its *properties* is a closure (`some_internal_function`) , but the object isn't. Interesting question, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, absolutely right, just tired. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to not use the anonymous module pattern. Consider the following:

```
var closure = aNameThatConveysWhatYourThingIs(document.getElementById("canvas"));

function aNameThatConveysWhatYourThingIs(some_variable) {
  var ret = {};

  function some_internal_function() {
      return some_variable;
  };

  ret.some_internal_function = some_internal_function;

  return ret;
}
```

This requires no stunts in order to achieve [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), which is what you are struggling with.

You can then, in your tests, simply call the function with a mocked dependency in order to access and make assertions on the state that is being manipulated.

---

Using the anonymous module pattern you:

- Get dependencies instead of asking for them.
- Tightly couple code in your module with its parent scope.

Resulting in that:

- It's hard to control the state that is being manipulated by the code, you have to be clever in order to do that instead of just having support for this.
- It's hard to separate the code from the context in which it's written.

These are are traits that are avert to testability that are inherent with the anonymous module pattern. Using it doesn't seem to cohere with the expectations that you have from your code.

Comment: I'm attempting to use [The Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html), thus the form. The edit appears to do both and follows the pattern I mentioned.

Comment: My answer specifies that you should neglect this pattern, because it does not suit your goals. Eating soup with a fork may be the coolest, but heck, if you ask me, a spoon is the way to go. I'll clarify my answer to convey that.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm a bit new to JS (mostly a Python background) so I'm trying to get a handle on the Way Things Are Done (TM). Let me know if this sounds right: You'd develop __without__ the module pattern (since it's a pain to test), then on deployment wrap it in a module pattern? I've seen something similar, but I haven't seen an article on best practices for development that outlines it explicitly. I have however seen the Module Pattern on deployed code everywhere, giving me the impression it's a good pattern to implement for deployment at least.

Comment: As for the module pattern being popular, that is indeed the case. However, I doubt that you'll find examples that use the module pattern in a way that prevents dependency injection in projects which are rigorously tested (such as Angular, for instance). As to where the module pattern won't affect your ability to test, this is a topic that's outside the scope of a comment, but perhaps it's worth updating my answer to clarify that. I'll probably do this today or tomorrow :)

Comment: Couldn't agree more. One more link and I think we've made this safe for future googlers: [Journey From RequireJS to Browserify](http://esa-matti.suuronen.org/blog/2013/03/22/journey-from-requirejs-to-browserify/). Which is essentially: break it down into bits you can test, then browserify it, which wraps it in a closure for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be a bit more complete:

http://superherojs.com/

- [Writing Testable Frontend Javascript Part 1 - Anti-patterns and their fixes](https://shanetomlinson.com/2013/testing-javascript-frontend-part-1-anti-patterns-and-fixes/)

  - Expose private methods for testing, then during the build process closure them to make them private again
  - Pass in a configuration object to be able to pass mock objects to your code during testing
- [Writing Testable JavaScript](http://www.adequatelygood.com/Writing-Testable-JavaScript.html)

  - Avoid singletons (like in the above code)
  - Avoid closure private variables (At least during testing and development, build is fine ^)
  - ([then a slight detour into what the prototype property is and how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype))
  - write your functions so they interact with global singletons as little as possible